# Choosing which pattern to use

Tags: scala

I have following trait:

```
sealed trait Sum[+A, +B] {
  def fold[C](error: A => C, success: B => C): C =
    this match {
      case Failure(v) => error(v)
      case Success(v) => success(v)
    }
}
final case class Failure[A](value: A) extends Sum[A, Nothing]
final case class Success[B](value: B) extends Sum[Nothing, B]
```

As you can see, there is a `fold` method implementation.

I could move the `fold` method into a companion object as follow:

```
sealed trait Sum[+A, +B]
final case class Failure[A](value: A) extends Sum[A, Nothing]
final case class Success[B](value: B) extends Sum[Nothing, B]

object Sum{
    def fold[A, B, C](s: Sum[A,B], error: A => C, success: B => C): C =
        s match {
          case Failure(v) => error(v)
          case Success(v) => success(v)
        }
}
```

What is more convenient pattern, the first or second example and in which situation?

Answer (score 1):

The latter will probably not work as you intend, since `this` in that case is the object `Sum` not the instance of either `Failure` or `Success`. 
Anyway, I'd move the implementations to case classes:

```
   case class Failure[A](value: A) extends Sum[A, Nothing] {
      def fold[C](error: A => C, success: B => C): C = error(value)
   }

   case class Success[A](value: B) extends Sum[A, Nothing] {
      def fold[C](error: A => C, success: B => C): C = success(value)
   }
```

Comment: Of course you'd have to declare `def fold...` in the base trait

Answer (score 0):

The second one doesn't work, since this is pointing to the Sum companion object, and the type variables A and B aren't defined.

Therefore use the first pattern!

Comment: You still use this in the fold method, which is always the Sum companion object

Comment: IT should be fine now.

Answer (score 0):

I'd prefer the first (or the modification in Tomasz Perek's answer). The second should be changed to

```
def fold[A, B, C](s: Sum[A,B])(error: A => C, success: B => C): C =
    s match {
      case Failure(v) => error(v)
      case Success(v) => success(v)
    }
```

so that the compiler already knows `A` and `B` by the time it gets to type-checking the `error` and `success` parameters.